# How to remove "Get Office" app?

Tags: windows-10

I would like to get rid of "Get Office" app. I mean this:

[image]

I have tried right-clicking and choosing "Uninstall". I have tried selecting it from the Apps and Features list.

There are also many examples available online on how to do it with the PowerShell, but it does not seem to work. I have tried commands such as these:

```
Get-AppxPackage|? name -like MicrosoftOfficeHub|remove-appxpackage
Get-AppxPackage -Name *officehub* | Remove-AppxPackage
```

But that icon is still there in the program list!

In one of the comments I was hinted that the app might have changed name, so I tried listing all of them. None resembles the "Get Office" though.

Any ideas?

Here is my complete list of installed apps. The Windows 10 is a nearly fresh installation. A notable p, with only Comodo Firewall and Visual Studio 2017 installed.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-AppxPackage | Select Name, PackageFullName

Name                                        PackageFullName
----                                        ---------------
Microsoft.AAD.BrokerPlugin                  Microsoft.AAD.BrokerPlugin_1000.16299.15.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
Microsoft.Windows.CloudExperienceHost       Microsoft.Windows.CloudExperienceHost_10.0.16299.15_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost       Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_10.0.16299.15_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
windows.immersivecontrolpanel               windows.immersivecontrolpanel_10.0.1.1000_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge                     Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_41.16299.15.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager    Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_10.0.16299.15_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.1.6          Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.1.6_1.6.24903.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.1.6          Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.1.6_1.6.24903.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.6            Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.6_1.6.24903.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.6            Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.6_1.6.24903.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Microsoft.BioEnrollment                     Microsoft.BioEnrollment_10.0.16299.15_neutral__cw5n1h2txyewy
Microsoft.CredDialogHost                    Microsoft.CredDialogHost_10.0.16299.15_neutral__cw5n1h2txyewy
Microsoft.ECApp                             Microsoft.ECApp_10.0.16299.15_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Microsoft.LockApp                           Microsoft.LockApp_10.0.16299.15_neutral__cw5n1h2txyewy
Microsoft.PPIProjection                     Microsoft.PPIProjection_10.0.16299.15_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
Microsoft.Windows.Apprep.ChxApp             Microsoft.Windows.Apprep.ChxApp_1000.16299.15.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
Microsoft.AccountsControl                   Microsoft.AccountsControl_10.0.16299.15_neutral__cw5n1h2txyewy
Microsoft.Windows.AssignedAccessLockApp     Microsoft.Windows.AssignedAccessLockApp_1000.16299.15.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
Microsoft.Windows.OOBENetworkCaptivePortal  Microsoft.Windows.OOBENetworkCaptivePortal_10.0.16299.15_neutral__cw5n1h2txyewy
Microsoft.Windows.OOBENetworkConnectionFlow Microsoft.Windows.OOBENetworkConnectionFlow_10.0.16299.15_neutral__cw5n1h2txyewy
Microsoft.Windows.ParentalControls          Microsoft.Windows.ParentalControls_1000.16299.15.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
1527c705-839a-4832-9118-54d4Bd6a0c89        1527c705-839a-4832-9118-54d4Bd6a0c89_10.0.16299.15_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
c5e2524a-ea46-4f67-841f-6a9465d9d515        c5e2524a-ea46-4f67-841f-6a9465d9d515_10.0.16299.15_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
E2A4F912-2574-4A75-9BB0-0D023378592B        E2A4F912-2574-4A75-9BB0-0D023378592B_10.0.16299.15_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
F46D4000-FD22-4DB4-AC8E-4E1DDDE828FE        F46D4000-FD22-4DB4-AC8E-4E1DDDE828FE_10.0.16299.15_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
InputApp                                    InputApp_1000.16299.15.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
Microsoft.Windows.PeopleExperienceHost      Microsoft.Windows.PeopleExperienceHost_10.0.16299.15_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
Microsoft.Windows.PinningConfirmationDialog Microsoft.Windows.PinningConfirmationDialog_1000.16299.15.0_neutral__cw5n1h2txyewy
Microsoft.Windows.SecHealthUI               Microsoft.Windows.SecHealthUI_10.0.16299.15_neutral__cw5n1h2txyewy
Microsoft.Windows.SecondaryTileExperience   Microsoft.Windows.SecondaryTileExperience_10.0.0.0_neutral__cw5n1h2txyewy
Windows.PrintDialog                         Windows.PrintDialog_6.2.0.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
Microsoft.XboxGameCallableUI                Microsoft.XboxGameCallableUI_1000.16299.15.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
Microsoft.Windows.SecureAssessmentBrowser   Microsoft.Windows.SecureAssessmentBrowser_10.0.16299.15_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
Microsoft.MicrosoftStickyNotes              Microsoft.MicrosoftStickyNotes_1.8.2.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00                     Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00_14.0.25426.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00                     Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00_14.0.25426.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Microsoft.Advertising.Xaml                  Microsoft.Advertising.Xaml_10.1711.2.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Microsoft.Advertising.Xaml                  Microsoft.Advertising.Xaml_10.1711.2.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Microsoft.VCLibs.120.00                     Microsoft.VCLibs.120.00_12.0.21005.1_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Microsoft.VCLibs.120.00                     Microsoft.VCLibs.120.00_12.0.21005.1_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.1.2          Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.1.2_1.2.23231.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.1.2          Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.1.2_1.2.23231.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.1            Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.1_1.1.23406.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.1            Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.1_1.1.23406.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Microsoft.Services.Store.Engagement         Microsoft.Services.Store.Engagement_10.0.17112.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Microsoft.Services.Store.Engagement         Microsoft.Services.Store.Engagement_10.0.17112.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Microsoft.WindowsCamera                     Microsoft.WindowsCamera_2017.921.10.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Microsoft.MSPaint                           Microsoft.MSPaint_3.1710.30027.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Microsoft.ZuneVideo                         Microsoft.ZuneVideo_10.17102.13911.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Microsoft.StorePurchaseApp                  Microsoft.StorePurchaseApp_11711.1711.20001.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Microsoft.Windows.Photos                    Microsoft.Windows.Photos_2017.39091.16340.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.UWPDesktop          Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.UWPDesktop_14.0.25426.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.UWPDesktop          Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.UWPDesktop_14.0.25426.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Microsoft.WindowsCalculator                 Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_10.1710.2791.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Microsoft.WindowsAlarms                     Microsoft.WindowsAlarms_10.1711.3041.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Microsoft.WindowsStore                      Microsoft.WindowsStore_11711.1001.5.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller               Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_1.0.12894.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Microsoft.WindowsSoundRecorder              Microsoft.WindowsSoundRecorder_10.1710.2861.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Microsoft.ZuneMusic                         Microsoft.ZuneMusic_10.17085.22311.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps         microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps_17.8730.21155.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Microsoft.Windows.Cortana                   Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_1.9.6.16299_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
Microsoft.Windows.HolographicFirstRun       Microsoft.Windows.HolographicFirstRun_10.0.16299.64_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
```

Comment: From the package list, it appears to have been removed successfully. The Start Menu database may be out of date.

Comment: How I would update the Start Menu database then? I just installed new software and it appeared (suggesting that the db is updated), but "Get Office" is still not removed.